# To resize multiple div without having to write multiple functions

Tags: jquery, html, resizable

For my project, I need to have multiple DIVs (one below one) of which all are resizable. I used resizable jquery to resize. But it seems that only one DIV can be activated using one resizeable function (in jquery). I tried with two resizable functions for 2 DIVs then it worked. So is there any way to resize multiple DIVs without having to rewrite the resizable function. Here is my javascript for resizable function

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizeDiv" ).resizable();
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="resizeDiv" class="ui-widget-content">                  
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Report 1</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of using the id. Put divs you want resized in a class and change that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/hu63rbxc/

```
<div class="resize"></div>
<div class="resize"></div>
<div class="resize"></div>
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$( ".resize" ).resizable();
```

Answer (score 1):

For this reason there are two selectors, i.e id and class. You have assigned id to div, so at a time you can only access one div. For multiple divs you need to assign any common class to all divs.

```
<div id="resizeDiv" class="ui-widget-content">                  
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Report 1</h3>
</div> 
<div id="resizeDiv2" class="ui-widget-content">                  
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Report 2</h3>
</div> 
<div id="resizeDiv3" class="ui-widget-content">                  
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Report 3</h3>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $( ".ui-widget-content" ).resizable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a new class to all the ones you want resized or you can add multiple selectors in your jquery

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizeDiv, #resizeDivtwo, #resizeDivthree" ).resizable();
});
```